# how does windows deal with drawing chars not in the current font

Tags: winapi

I have an app that is trying to display U+23CE (`⏎`). This is a terminal app, so we are using "Consolas"/"Cascadia"/"Courier". As far as I can see, none of these fonts have this character. And yet, in Visual Studio, when I am debugging this app, it actually displays it correctly in the debugger. Also, when displayed by the new Windows Terminal, it displays correctly. But when I use the app I am working with (actually Putty), it displays the "I don't know this character" glyph.

Putty is a classic Win32 app using `ExtTextOutW()` to draw that text. I have checked that the correct font is bound to the `HDC`.

I am assuming that Visual Studio and Windows Terminal are using DirectWrite or other more modern text output logic, but ultimately they have to be getting these unknown glyphs from somewhere.

UPDATE:

I found a font with that character ("Segue UI Symbol"), and if I set Putty to use that font, it displays the missing character (woohoo). Sadly, this is a proportional font, so it looks terrible, and this is not the solution.

@dvix pointed me at a Microsoft page discussing this exact topic, but its not clear which things are done by Windows and which by an app developer. I tried linking "Courier New" (Putty's default) to "Segoe Symbol"", but it made no difference. Does the Putty code need to do all the work itself? Detect an unknown character, read the Registry, and substitute the font for that one char? That is certainly doable, but a pain.

Comment: I guess the consoles are using [font fallback and linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology).

Comment: @dvix the problem with that link is that its for users. It says, everything happens by magic. It even says 'we added an api in windows 8' but doesnt say what it is.

Comment: @dvix - ok that fixed it, just had to log out. Ty, please make it answer

Comment: Font linking used to "just work" back in WinXP/7 without any app-side support. The old [version of the same article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160516075653/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx) went into some more detail. Not sure what the related options and best practices are in Win10 nowadays, which a good answer would be expected to cover.

Comment: @dvix yes it just worked once I realized that I had to log on and off. PLease make your comment into an answer ("you need to set  up font linking")

Comment: Took another quick look at this, just enough to lose hope that it can be fully covered in a single answer here ;-) Hope someone with more (time and) dedication may find the pointers below to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Windows can be directed to "borrow" missing glyphs in a font from another font that carries them using [font linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-linking). This applies to both consoles and GUI apps that use GDI (DrawText, ExtTextOut) to render text in Windows 2000 and later.

For example, the following registry entry will link the *Consolas* font to *Segoe UI Symbol* (the following can be saved as a `.reg` file and merged into the registry, will take effect at the next logon).

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink]
"Consolas"=hex(7):53,45,47,55,49,53,59,4d,2e,54,54,46,2c,53,65,\
                  67,6f,65,20,55,49,20,53,79,6d,62,6f,6c,00,00
; "Consolas"=REG_MULTI_SZ:"SEGUISYM.TTF,Segoe UI Symbol"
```

One handy tool to explore coverage of the different fonts is [BabelMap](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html). For example this is the list of fonts that carry U+23CE (⏎) on a fairly clean Win10 system.

[image]

Another feature of BabelMap is the option to create temporary user-defined composite fonts on the fly, as opposed to the ones "statically" defined in the registry. This is presumably done using the [MLang](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767865(v=vs.85))
[IMLangFontLink interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741048(v=vs.85)), more about that in Raymond Chen's [How to display a string without those ugly boxes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040716-00/?p=38413) and Michael Kaplan's [Font substitution and linking #2](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/05/16/417711.html).

Comment: @pm100 That *is* a cool tool, indeed. Would have also been pretty educational if it were open source, unfortunately it's not. As for DirectWrite, I am not really familiar with that. Seems to be a DirectX API for Win7+ only, with [some features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/programming-guide) apparently Win8+ only. I expect there must be a whitepaper somewhere with a side by side comparison against Uniscribe etc, but I don't see it on the first page of google hits ;-)